# How to show custom error messages in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to show a user defined error message once a query executes.
For example I have a table names COA and I am deleting a record from this table whose ID is `200001`, I want to display a message at the bottom which in case ID is not present in the table says "ID is not present" or something custom defined.

```
  DELETE FROM [dbo].[COA]
  WHERE ID = 200001
  IF [dbo].[COA].ID <> 200001
  PRINT N'The current database is master.';
```

Is this possible or not ?

Comment: `IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 ...` (Note that if the entire *table* doesn't exist because you're in the wrong database, you'll just get a compile error instead, and that sort of stuff can be captured only with `TRY .. CATCH`... well, [maybe](http://sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part2.html#bindingerrors)).

Comment: You could use `@@ROWCOUNT` for this:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: SQL Server itself doesn't have UI. So it has no means to "display a message at the bottom". If you're using the standard SQL Server *client* tools there's also not much means to control the UI. If you're writing your own application that communicates with SQL Server and presents UI then you do have far more options but we'd have to understand what technologies you're using for that application.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [**`OUTPUT`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) clause in the `DELETE` statement in order to store the rows deleted, if any:

```
DECLARE @MyTableVar TABLE  
(  
    ID INT
);  

DELETE FROM [dbo].[COA]
OUTPUT DELETED.ID INTO @MyTableVar
WHERE ID = 200001

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @MyTableVar)
  PRINT N'The current database is master.';
```

**Note:** You can define `@MyTableVar` to include additional fields from the original table, so that you are able to create a more customized message.

Comment: Much better than using the @@ROWCOUNT because when you want to delete 5 records and only 4 are deleted @@ROWCOUNT will still be different then 0 and now you can show what was deleted exact

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this...

```
DELETE FROM [dbo].[TableName]
WHERE ID = '1'
IF (@@rowcount < 1 ) 
BEGIN
    PRINT N'ID is not present.'; 
END
```